# The instance member 'userEmail' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, instance, initializer

The above error message is being displayed in my code. Please see below:

```
class BottomNaviBar extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'bottom_navi_bar';

  @override
  _BottomNaviBarState createState() => _BottomNaviBarState();
}

class _BottomNaviBarState extends State<BottomNaviBar> {
  int selectedIndex = 0;
  bool showRecipeNotificationBadge = false;
  bool showProfileNotificationBadge = false;
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  FirebaseUser loggedInUser;
  String userEmail;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = await _auth.currentUser();
      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
          userEmail = user.email;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }


  List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    RecipeBlog(),
    FavouritesScreen(userEmail: userEmail,), //this is what is causing the error
    ProperHomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  ...
```

Its strange, because if I pass an actual user's email address into the `FavouritesScreen()` as a hard-coded string, the code works perfectly. But it doesn't work otherwise.

Any ideas?

UPDATED ON 02/10/20:

For more context, here's the code for `build`:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> _widgetOptions() {
      return [
        RecipeBlog(),
        FavouritesScreen(userEmail: userEmail,),
        ProperHomeScreen(),
        ProfileScreen(),
      ];
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          // sets the background color of the `BottomNavigationBar`
          canvasColor: Color(0xFF150A42),
          // sets the active color of the `BottomNavigationBar` if `Brightness` is light
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              title: Container(),
            ),

            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.redAccent,),
              title: Container(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.forum),
                showRecipeNotificationBadge != false
                    ? Positioned(
                  top: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1,
                      size: 12.0, color: Color(0x00000000)),
                )
                    : Positioned(
                  top: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1,
                      size: 12.0, color: Colors.redAccent),
                ),
              ]),
              title: Container(),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.person),
                showProfileNotificationBadge != false
                    ? Positioned(
                  top: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1,
                      size: 12.0, color: Color(0x00000000)),
                )
                    : Positioned(
                  top: 0.0,
                  right: 0.0,
                  child: Icon(Icons.brightness_1,
                      size: 12.0, color: Colors.redAccent),
                ),
              ]),
              title: Container(),
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Color(0xFF150A42),
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black38,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: selectedIndex == 0 ? null : FloatingActionButton(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff02aab0),
        onPressed: () {Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BottomNaviBar()),
        );},
        child: Icon(Icons.search),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Hi Christopher, thank you very much for your answer, and apologies for the really delayed response. I've tried your answer, but I then get a new error displayed in ```build```. In the ```return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(selectedIndex),
      ),```, an error message then gets displayed saying ```Error: The method 'elementAt' isn't defined for the class 'List<Widget> Function()'.```. any ideas please? I've updated my question to include the entire updated code based on your answer, for more context.

Comment: You're not calling the function. You're trying to execute a method on a function reference, not the return value of the function. Do `_widgetOptions().elementAt`

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Thank you so much for your help, that works perfectly now. I have accepted your answer. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error states that you cannot use instance members in initializers. This means that you cannot use another instance variable to initialize an instance variable.

A simple example:

```dart
class Test {
  String initial = "this thing";
  String other = initial;//This leads to the same error that you have
}
```

This is because initializers are executed before the constructor. This means there is no way to access `this` at initialization time, which is called implicitly when you access instance members. When you hardcode a value, `this` is no longer necessary to initialize the variable so it works.

With the previous example, calling `initial` is really doing `this.initial`, but `this` is not available, so it will not work.

A workaround would be to change the initialization of `_widgetOptions` to `initState`.

---

However, trying to do what you show in your question is not advisable in the first place. `Widget`s shouldn't be stored in variables except for maybe very special cases. This is because when you update the parameters you want to pass to a widget, the widget object itself will not update so no visual changes will be seen on a rebuild.

Instead make `_widgetOptions` a function that you call in `build` that returns your `List` of `Widget`s so that new `Widget` objects are created every time the function is called:

```dart
List<Widget> _widgetOptions() {
  return [
    RecipeBlog(),
    FavouritesScreen(userEmail: userEmail,),
    ProperHomeScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];
}
```

This method also inherently removes the current error you're receiving with no extra work as the method can't be called before the constructor creates `this`.

Comment: You definitely want to try to avoid storing widgets. That's usually a sign of something else not being right. Instead use the function approach higlighted by @Christopher Moore at the end of his reply

Comment: hi, in your simple example i want to use this in my class so is it another way to use this style ?